# Model renders black in libGdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, blender, 3d-model

After I updated my OS, i found that my models were not rendering their textures properly in LibGDX. The model would appear black instead of having a texture. This happened right after i updated my OS so, i don't know if it has anything to do with that.

Here is how it looks in blender:
[image]

and Here is how it looks in libGdx:

[image]

Notice how the textures for the model are not rendering.

Here is my create() method:

```
public void create () {
camera=new PerspectiveCamera(67,800,480);
camera.position.set(0f, 0f, 10f);
camera.lookAt(0f, 0f, 0f);
camera.near=1f;
camera.far=50f;

batch=new ModelBatch();
UBJsonReader jsonreader=new UBJsonReader();
G3dModelLoader modelloader=new G3dModelLoader(jsonreader);
playermodel=modelloader.loadModel(Gdx.files.getFileHandle("paulmodel.g3db", Files.FileType.Internal));
player=new ModelInstance(playermodel,0,0,0);


environment=new Environment();
environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight,0.65f,0.65f,0.65f,1f));


}
```

Here is my Render() method:

```
public void render () {
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
camera.update();
batch.begin(camera);
batch.render(player, environment);
batch.end();
camera.rotateAround(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f), new Vector3(0f, 1f, 0f), 0.5f);
}
```

Here is my [model](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jpzza8ova87oxty/paulmodel.g3db?dl=0)

Also, i seem to begetting an error `distrib/android-emugl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glActiveTexture:177 error 0x500`

If you need anything else, please ask and i will post it.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Here is the [.G3dJ](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u5e3g4a8oj7cvmu/paulmodel.g3dj?dl=0) file as requested.

**EDIT:
It works perfectly fine on a real phone but, it doesn't work on an AVD. Does this mean that it should work on all phones? Also, i have made the textures in the format of 2^n by 2^n pixels.**

Comment: I had a similar problem caused by using non-power of two sized textures (see [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26187/why-are-textures-always-square-powers-of-two-what-if-they-arent)) where everything rendered green on one device, but correctly on another, could be worth a look

Comment: That error 0x500 is INVALID_ENUM. So I would set a checkpoint at `GL20.glActiveTexture (int texture)` and make sure the passed in integer is valid. Should be something between 0x84C0 and 0x84DF. If it's not, maybe something is wrong with the model file, or there's a bug in your phone's ROM. Don't really know what could cause it.

Comment: @rbennett485 I just tried that and it still doesn't work. Also, The textuers only render on the closest part of the model to the camera

Comment: @Tenfour04 I don't call the GL20.glActiveTexture() method. I think that the ModelBatch.render() method takes care of that. Thank you for your time though. Could you also look at my model file and tell me if i have done something wrong? thanks again!

Comment: I know you don't call it direftly, but you can still set a breakpoint and see if something is going wrong. Just a suggestion, not an expert in this area.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I set a breakpoint and nothing seems to go wrong other than that error i am getting. could it have something to do with the model?

Comment: You say nothing "seems" to go wrong. Is the integer getting passed to `glActiveTexture` a valid one? ( a value between 0x84C0 and 0x84DF) If not, then you can debug back from there. Also, if you create a G3DJ instead of G3DB, anyone can look at your model file itself and tell right away if something is wrong with it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have add the .G3dJ file.(look at bottom part of question) Sorry for my late response.

Comment: remove the environment, see also https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Importing-Blender-models-in-LibGDX

Comment: @Xoppa I removed the environment but it makes no difference.